# Java dynamic proxies - class implements multiple interfaces

Tags: java

I'm looking at some Java dynamic proxies examples. A basic one which simply intercepts a method call and add some print-out:

```
public interface IVehicle {
    public void forward();
}

public class Car implements IVehicle {
    private String name;

    public Car(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public void forward() {
        System.out.println("Car " + name + " forward");
    }
}

public class VehicleHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private Car v;
    public VehicleHandler(Car v) {this.v = v;}
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Vehicle Handler: Invoking " + m.getName());
        return m.invoke(v, args);
    }
}

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car c = new Car("audi");
        ClassLoader cl = Car.class.getClassLoader();
        IVehicle v = (IVehicle) Proxy.newProxyInstance(cl,
            new Class[] {IVehicle.class}, new VehicleHandler(c));

        v.forward();
    }
}
```

This example works well and prints out handler and object messages. But then I'm thinking what if the Car class in above example implements multiple interfaces and I call all methods in all implemented interfaces?

I edited above example to (Changes are surrounded by **):

```
public interface IVehicle {
    public void forward();
}

**public interface IVehicle2 {
    public void forward2();
}**

public class Car implements IVehicle, **IVehicle2** {
    private String name;

    public Car(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public void forward() {
        System.out.println("Car " + name + " forward");
    }

    **public void forward2() {
        System.out.println("Car " + name + " forward2");
    }**
}

public class VehicleHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private Car v;
    public VehicleHandler(Car v) {this.v = v;}
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Vehicle Handler: Invoking " + m.getName());
        return m.invoke(v, args);
    }
}

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car c = new Car("audi");
        ClassLoader cl = Car.class.getClassLoader();
        **Car** v = **(Car)** Proxy.newProxyInstance(cl,
            new Class[] {IVehicle.class, **IVehicle2.class**}, new VehicleHandler(c));

        v.forward();
        **v.forward2();**
    }
}
```

I got below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to class Car
```

My questions are:
1. why do I get above error?
2. How do I correctly do proxy if I want to call both `forward()` and `forward2()` in above example?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why do you need all that? Car c = new Car("Audi"); already gives you your Car instance. I don't understand what you are trying to do here

Comment: You can not cast the proxy to `Car`. It implements the same interfaces as `Car`, but it is NOT a `Car`.

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing the Proxy class, `i.e. Car` at compile time. The idea of dynamic proxy is to have the 'proxy class' generated at runtime, i.e. the proxy class implementation at compile time is not needed.

In this code snippet

```
**Car** v = **(Car)** Proxy.newProxyInstance(cl,
        new Class[] {IVehicle.class, **IVehicle2.class**}, new VehicleHandler(c));
```

Have the proxy instance assigned to one of interface that it implements. Based on the interface it's assigned to, the corresponding method can be invoked on the proxy.

If you want a `single proxy` that can invoke either of the interface's method, then have a common interface that extends both `IVehicle` and `IVehicle2`; and then use the common interface as the proxy class, i.e. (assign proxy rcvd. through `Proxy.newProxyInstance` to the common interface.

Note: the `Car` class can be used for other purposes it may have, including it being the loader class. When using it as the proxy class, `i.e.**Car** v = **(Car)** Proxy.newProxyInstance` it's not a dynamic proxy class.